# How to get read multiple rows in single column Data?

Tags: c#

I have 7 Textboxes, and Data i have to fetch from Single col and 7 rows and assign to the 7 textboxes,

E.g

| **DefectStatus** |
| --- |
| None |
| None |
| None |

```
}
    OldbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DefectStatus FROM TblProductionData WHERE SerialNumber='" + TxtSerialNo.Text.Trim() + "'", ClsGlobals.con);
            OldbReader = OldbCommand.ExecuteReader();
}

        
while ( OldbReader.Read())
{
    TxtCell1Status.Text = OldbReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    TxtCell2Status.Text =  I dont know how to get value from second row
 
}
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to research "C# how to get value from second row in OleDbReader" ? But nevertheless, this command: `OldbReader.Read()` reads actually one row. you would need to repeat the step in the loop to get the next row. I would suggest to put all your textboxes in an array with a specified order and iterate through the array while you read row for row, each row choosing the next textbox

Comment: Your reader, reads one object at a time. 
You will need to assign a different cell, pr object. 

I would normally recommend you simply use a datagrid, rather than a textbox, and just supply our database result as datasource. This will likely make your life easier. 

Also, it's not OLD, it's Ole. ;) well, it is old, but that isn't the point :D

Comment: Yes I have Pass second row value to this textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var textBoxes = new[]
                {
                    TxtCell1Status,
                    TxtCell2Status,
                    TxtCell3Status,
                    ...
                }

foreach (var tb in textBoxes)
{
    OldbReader.Read();
    tb.Text = OldbReader.GetString(0);
}
```

This assumes that there will always be at least as many rows as there are `TextBoxes`.

Comment: Yes, it is done, all rows' values are getting one by one. Thanks @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TextBox> listOfTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell1Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell2Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell3Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell4Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell5Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell6Status);
listOfTextBoxes.Add(TxtCell7Status);

int count = 0;
while ( OldbReader.Read())
{
    listOfTextBoxes[count].Text = OldbReader.GetValue(0).ToString()
    count++;
}
```

I DID NOT VERIFY THIS BUILDS - TREAT IT AS PSEUDO CODE.

The problem here is you NEED to know how many results you will get, or your UI will likely fail to display the required data, or just throw an exception.

You should use a gridview instead, and assign your result as a data source.

Also this code is heinously dirty. You should initialise objects, away from logic, you should make your code way more readable.

So treat this code with all the contempt it deserves.

Comment: Here only get first row data. I have need to get7 rows data

Comment: Would you check the table you have (TblProductionData) actually has 7 rows?

Comment: @Arshad, you are incorrect. This code is calling `Read` once for each `TextBox`, so it will work as intended. Your original code doesn't work because you were trying to set all `Textboxes` every time you call `Read`.

Comment: Into this table TblProductionData each model number has 7 records.

Comment: @Arshad Then this code does what you want. 
Or I am misunderstanding what you want. 

The "while" loop, executes until you have no more reads left. 
if your queries has 7 tows, this will insert the status on each row, into a separate text field. Notice that I am adding 7 different textfields in the list. And assigning the textfield based on the count that is increased each time the loop completes.